# How do I shoot in tethered mode using own software to control the camera?

Tags: canon, software, tethering, eos-utility

Is it possible to capture image from computer with Canon EOS camera and save it to computer? Can the EOS utility used for this?

I want to use my own software (written in Java) to control the camera from the computer and capture images.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want. Could you explain your situation a bit more please?

Comment: I think they want to write a program in Java to control the camera and capture the image, just like EOS Utility does. Is that right? Please edit your question.

Comment: Ah I see. But the `camera in background` part is still not clear then.

Comment: I'm sorry my question isn't clear. As Paul Cezanne says, I want to write a program in Java to control the EOS camera and capture the image.

Comment: So edit the question to say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As A F said, it's possible to use Canon EDSDK and it's Java wrapper - https://github.com/kritzikratzi/edsdk4j/wiki. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Technically they call it "Tethering Capture" from computer.
For example Photoshop Lightroom supports some of EOS cameras for tethering. Please see:
http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support-lightroom-4.html

The "EOS Utility software" does also support tethering/remote shooting. From the menu, choose “Camera settings/Remote shooting”.
Please see the following link for further information:
http://www.beyondmegapixels.com/2011/02/tethered-shooting-with-a-canon-dslr/

Comment: For your program, you may use "Canon Digital Camera Software Developer's Kit"[link]http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage

It does not support Java language though.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are asking can the computer control an EOS camera and take pictures without a photographer's interaction the answer is *Yes*.** There are some limits to what you may do via EOS Utility, the primary one being that you can't change the focal length of a zoom lens without physically moving the zoom ring (or the push/pull barrel) on the lens. You can adjust focus, aperture, ISO, shutter speed, WB, and many other parameters via the tethered interface. You can also set the program up to automatically take time lapse shots at specific intervals. If you plan on continuous shots for more than a couple of hours, you need to use an external power supply or the camera will only shoot until the battery is depleted. You also need to insure adequate space on either the camera's memory card or the computer's disk and be sure to specify the correct location to save the files.

If you are asking can the computer be used for the camera to take a picture of itself being shown on the screen of the computer the answer is, "Not without a mirror as well." You would still need to either turn off the LCD screen on the back of the camera or risk optical feedback in the image.

Comment: `risk optical feedback in the image`. Is this really a risk (i.e. risk of damage), or just a way of saying? If it's the first, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The *risk* is at two levels. The first is a risk of resulting artifacts in the image, even if there is no damage to the camera. The second is risk that if the intensity of the light is strong enough it could potentially damage either the LCD screen on the camera, the display on the computer, or even the sensor on the camera.

Comment: @MichaelClark - if there is any display that is capable of making light bright enough to damage a camera, where has it been hiding all these years?  That would have to be one very very bright display (probably impossible).  Also, displaying pure white shouldn't damage a screen unless it is very poorly designed indeed.

Comment: Back in the old days you could certainly fry the screen on a studio grade video camera with feedback by pointing it at the image it was sending to a monitor. Of course those were CRT, not LCD displays that are common now. As far as the sensor goes, strong sunlight and lasers supposedly safe for humans to look at have been known to burn out pixels on a CMOS sensor inside a DSLR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to hook up to the camera and capture images outside of EOS Utility.  This can be seen in multiple programs available for Android and iOS which do specifically this.  As far as how to write a program to do that, that's unfortunately a programing question, not a photography one and is off topic for Photography.  You'd probably have better luck on StackOverflow.